# Expecting member declaration in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to assign my class variable in constructor, but I get an error 'expecting member declaration'

```kotlin
class YLAService {

    var context:Context?=null

    class YLAService constructor(context: Context) {
        this.context=context;// do something
    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Kotlin you can use constructors like so:

```
class YLAService constructor(val context: Context) {

}
```

Even shorter:

```
class YLAService(val context: Context) {

}
```

If you want to do some processing first:

```
class YLAService(context: Context) {

  val locationService: LocationManager

  init {
    locationService = context.getService(LocationManager::class.java)
  }
}
```

If you really want to use a secondary constructor:

```
class YLAService {

  val context: Context

  constructor(context: Context) {
    this.context = context
  }

}
```

This looks more like the Java variant, but is more verbose.

See the [Kotlin reference on constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

Comment: Thank you, But I Also do something inside constructor

Comment: @hugerde what about using `init {}` block?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov Thank you, This is what I need, I will use init block with constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add some info and give real example. When you want to initialize class && trigger some event, like some method, in **Python** we can simply call `self.some_func()` being in `__init__` or even outside. In **Kotlin** we're restricted from calling simple in the context of the class, i.e.:

```sh
class SomeClass {
    this.cannotCallFunctionFromHere()
}
```

For such purposes I use `init`. It's different from constructor in a way that we don't clutter class schema && allows to make some processing.

Example where we call `this.traverseNodes`  before any further actions are done with the methods, i.e. it's done during class initialization:

```sh
class BSTIterator(root: TreeNode?) {
    private var nodes = mutableListOf<Int>()
    private var idx: Int = 0
    
    init {
        this.traverseNodes(root)
    }
    
    
    fun next(): Int {
        val return_node = this.nodes[this.idx]
        this.idx += 1
        return return_node
    }

    fun hasNext(): Boolean {
        when {
            this.idx < this.nodes.size -> {
                return true
            } else -> {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun traverseNodes(node: TreeNode?) {
        if(node!!.left != null) {
            this.traverseNodes(node.left)
        }
        this.nodes.add(node.`val`)
        if(node!!.right != null) {
            this.traverseNodes(node.right)
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it also helps someone