# Implementing click listener for RecyclerView adapter correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

What's the correct way to create a click listener for an item in a `RecyclerView` adapter? [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6GSQRnDGog) says it should be done in `onBindViewHolder` but others have said in `onCreateViewHolder` and I've not seen any tutorials for the latter hence I'm perplexed.

```
class MyRVAdapter(private val myList: ArrayList<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder (itemView : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        // val myButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_A)!!
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.myButton.text = (myList[position].btnTitle)
     }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_cv, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)

        val myButton = v.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_A)!!

        myButton.setOnClickListener {
            customView = View.inflate(holder.itemView.context, R.layout.fragment_dialog, null)

                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(holder.itemView.context)
                builder.setIconAttribute(R.attr.imgInfo)
                builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
                builder.setView(customView)
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok){ dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }
                builder.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its you again), I thought you understood what I suggested. Just cut the code in onBindViewHolder() which is holder.myButton.setOnClickListener {//all the code } and paste to `class ViewHolder` and remove all `holder.`

Comment: @underoid Would I move `holder: ViewHolder` to `onCreateViewHolder`?

Comment: You don't need to do anything else. Do you still have problem?

Comment: @underoid Yep. I also get this error: `'onCreateViewHolder' overrides nothing`.

Comment: @MacaronLover use click listener inside onBindViewHolder itself. the usage of onClickListener was used in Java. new use click listeners before creating the view. it may throw errors or exceptions. so its good to use onClickListener in onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Kotlin**

In Kotlin you cant implement onClickListener in ViewHolderClass directly. 
In Kotlin to achieve the same, you have to do onClickListener inside `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.myButton.setOnClickListener {
            //do your stuff here
}
```

or use init function

```
// I'm not sure this is a correct method or not

class MyRVAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyRVAdapter.ViewHolder {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var myButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button) as Button

         // use any of the following declaratons
         // val myButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
         // val myButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
         // var myButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
         // var myButton:Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button)
         // val myButton:Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button)


        // to avoid Expecting Member Declaration is showing in kotlin  use constructor
       // Expecting Member Declaration is showing because kotlin allows null declaration so a constructor or init is required to avoid this
        init {
            myButton.setOnClickListener{
                //do your stuff here
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**In Java**

`onBindViewHolder` will be executed whenever there is a change in data. So it is good to write the `onClickListener` in The `ViewHolderClass`.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
            //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion. I just tried it with kotlin now. kotlin is not allowing the same as java

Comment: @MacaronLover I had updated my answer with explaination . Try reading that. I think it will help you. And go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368741/expecting-member-declaration-in-kotlin

Comment: Only thing you answer except the things i have already answered is:  _In Kotlin you cant implement onClickListener in ViewHolderClass._  and that is not right.

Comment: Which one is better to use?: `val myButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)!!` or `var myButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button) as Button`?

Comment: @MacaronLover as Button is useless see my answer

Comment: @MacaronLover val. since it is not changing we can use val.

Answer (score 0):

`onBindViewHolder()` will be called all the time when your Views appear on the screen so it is called more that your items' count. You will create lots of duplicate listeners when you scroll. Setting listener in ViewHolder will create one listener per holder. Here is the code:

```
class MyRVAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.myButton.text = "set here all except listener"
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_cv, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder (itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var myButton: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_A)

        init {
            myButton.setOnClickListener {
                val customView = View.inflate(itemView.context, R.layout.fragment_dialog, null)

                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(itemView.context)
                builder.setIconAttribute(R.attr.imgNight)
                builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
                builder.setView(customView)
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok){ dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }
                builder.show()

                val tabLayout = customView.findViewById(R.id.mTabLayout)
                val viewPager = customView.findViewById(R.id.mViewPager)

                val adapter = TabbedDialogAdapter(childFragmentManager)//i dont understand how you get this but it is another question
                adapter.addFragment("Tab A", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description A"))
                adapter.addFragment("Tab B", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description B"))
                adapter.addFragment("Tab C", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description C"))

                viewPager.adapter = adapter
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
            }
        }
    }
}
```